# How to calculate profits from a short position

Tags: calculation, shorting-securities, rate-of-return

Say I have a $100 balance, the margin requirement is 10%, I short a stock at $100, and the stock drops down to $10, is my profit 90% or 1000%? To more more specific, is the profit 90% relative to my balance and 1000% relative to my initial margin?